# Adding a dependencies to a child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I want to present a custom view controller within a navigation controller within modal view. To do this I made a view in interface builder, added a container view, and embedded the contained view in a navigation controller. The contained view is my custom view controller, DetailViewController.

[image]

I have to add dependencies to the DetailViewController object to at runtime. Here’s the method where I’ll be presenting the DetailViewController:

```
override func tableView(_: UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath) {
    guard let record = records[didSelectRowAt.row] else { return }
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let containerView = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailContainer")
    containerView.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    self.present(detailContainer, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I add the record to DetailViewController? I tried to access children of the container view, but the array is empty. [This Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) says

> The children must be instantiated at the same time as the parent so that the appropriate parent-child relationships can be created.

I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582200/how-do-i-get-the-views-inside-a-container-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

`containerView.children` is empty because viewcontroller's view isn't loaded.
You can force to load view by calling `containerView.view` thereafter `containerView.children` will exist.